# How to call a jQuery function on button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a function on button click with a dynamic parameter passed to that function.

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick=getvalue(val['id']):void(0);>Click</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function getvalue(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Any error in `console` ?

Comment: that's not valid html/javascript and absolutely no jquery involved - at least you didn't get jquery absolutely wrong

Comment: it shows nothing... getting confuse is this  possible ..?

Comment: i did something like same in past ... but forget ... please guide as i have to pass dynamic variable into function ...

Comment: val['id'] is a javascript variable?

Comment: function needs to be passed in quotes try ` <button onclick="getvalue('someid')">Click</button>`

Comment: yes @madlin val['id'] is dyamic variable..

Comment: @HiteshChauhan : what value you getting in val['id'] .. does that work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did that it was a tiny mistake

```
<a href="#" class="pull-right button uppercase" onclick="getvalue('+val['id']+');">Click</a>

function getvalue(val){

     alert(val);
}
```

one more thing if you don't want to load your page just replace # > javascript:void(0) in href .

Answer (score 7):

You need to put the attribute in quotes because there are quotes in the value. Also, you have a syntax error with `:void(0);` after the function call.

```
<button id="button1" onclick="getvalue(this.id);">Click</button>
```

Or you can give the element an ID and bind the click handler in jQuery.

```
<button class="mybuttons" id="button1">Click</button>

<script>
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
    getvalue(this.id);
});
</script>
```

Comment: My guess is OP does not want to submit the form on button `click`.. `type = "button"` will be needed...+1

Comment: There's no form in the question.

Comment: i need to suply dynamic variable into the function ... as Button is running in   for loop and every button has different id ....

Comment: Maybe you mean to use `this.id` to get the ID of the button that they click?

Comment: @Barmar but the button has no id nothing in it actually

Comment: You said "every button has a different id". Where does the dynamic variable come from if not the ID?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display(el) {
        var id = $(el).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    }
</script>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" OnClick="display(this);" />
```

[How to pass parameter to click event in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350860/how-to-pass-parameter-to-click-event-in-jquery)